# Unable to load angular in production

Tags: angular-cli

I am attempting to access the angular frontend in a production build. I am wrapping it in a servlet. When I attempt to access the paths, I get the following:

http://localhost:8080/app/index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>App</title>
  <base href="/app/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.bb3ec5518a780b95f31d.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.df1101cc1e7b588877f8.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.539e754fcc6ef28df40f.js" defer></script><script src="main-es2015.b18181d4c0f94e66b234.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.b18181d4c0f94e66b234.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

I get the following results when attempting to load 3 of the javascript files.

> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js:1
>
> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js:1
>
> Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec. main-es2015.b18181d4c0f94e66b234.js:1
>
> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain: "http://localhost:8080/app/styles.bb3ec5518a780b95f31d.css" index.html:12

Answer (score 0):

Dumb part on my side. I forgot to put the Response.setResponseType(...) in the servlet for the js and css files.